# How to convert promise <any> to promise <entity>

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, nestjs, typeorm

I am new to this typescript, nestjs. I want to know how can I convert `Promise<any[]>` to `Promise<MyEntity[]>` so that I can successfully excute this code I created:

```
 const usersfromTransaction = this.repoTransaction
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .select('user_id', 'id')
      .distinctOn(['user_id'])
      //.leftJoinAndSelect("user", "user")
      .where('EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_date)=EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW())')
      .andWhere('extract(month from created_Date)=extract(month from now())')
      .limit(10)
      .getRawMany();

    const users = this.repoUser.find(usersfromTransaction);

    return user;
```

User entity:

```
@Entity()
export class User {
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
id:string;
 @Column({ nullable: true })
firstname:string;
 @Column({ nullable: true })
lastname:string;
}
```

There error is from this line of code `this.repoUser.find(usersfromTransaction);`

Comment: what's the TS type of `repoUser`?

Comment: @MicaelLevi, updated this question sir.

Comment: you didn't show from where `this.repoUser` came from. If you have used a [custom typeorm repository](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#custom-repository) instead, then the type of `users` will be `Promise<User[]>`. Try it first

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert it to `unknown` or `any` first, like so...

```
const usersfromTransaction = ......... as unknown as Promise<MyEntity[]>;
```